# Open Report Use Three Combobox Filter

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have 3 combobox to filter data, then i want to open in command button to print preview..
Problems I have if i used 2 combobox it works but when i used three combobox the report is blank...there's any problems with the code?? here's the code i used :

```
Dim strWhereCondition As String
strWhereCondition = "[month] = '" & Me.cbmonth.Value _
                    & "' and [Works] = '" & Me.cbwork.Value _
                    & "' and [Works] = '" & Me.cbwork2.Value & "'"

Debug.Print strWhereCondition
DoCmd.OpenReport "Month List", View:=acViewPreview, _
WhereCondition:=strWhereCondition
```

and the requery for my form

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable 
WHERE (month = Forms!nameForm!cbmonth
OR Forms!MeForm!cbwork IS NULL)
And (works = Forms!nameForm!cbwork
OR Forms!nameForm!cbwork IS NULL)
AND (works = Forms!nameForm!cbwork2
OR Forms!nameForm!cbwork2 IS NULL);
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

Month is a number, so try:

```
strWhereCondition = "[month] = " & Me.cbmonth.Value _
                & " and [Works] = '" & Me.cbwork.Value _
                & "' and [Works] = '" & Me.cbwork2.Value & "'"
```

Edit: Month is text.

However, [Work] is supposed to match two potentially different values:

```
& "' and [Works] = '" & Me.cbwork.Value _
& "' and [Works] = '" & Me.cbwork2.Value & "'"
```

Should most likely be:

```
& "' and [Works] = '" & Me.cbwork.Value _
& "' and [SomeOtherField] = '" & Me.cbwork2.Value & "'"
```

Comment: yes im sorry its text... example Januari, Februari etc.

Comment: field [Works] its on the same field..so the code cant filter the data on the same field??

Comment: Yes, but the two combos must return the same value - a bit odd - if any records should be returned. Again, study your secret output from Debug.Print.